# Plotly.express graph returns None

Tags: python, plotly-python

I want to calculating a stock return daily by it's data frame. However, the out put of the fig command just show **None**.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", marginal_y="violin",
           marginal_x="box", trendline="ols", template="simple_white")

print(fig.show())
```

***Edited***:
My problem above has been solved. However, what about the following? Nothing appears.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species", marginal_y="violin", marginal_x="box", trendline="ols", template="simple_white")

fig.show()
```

Comment: I've tried your code. I got this error, so I guess I'm missing a necessary module. if I run it in google colaboratory where statsmodels is installed, the graph shows up.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do `fig.show()` at the end, not `print(fig.show())`